# where to find good examples of combinatorics (online resources only please)?

Tags: combinatorics, self-learning, learning, online-resources

one of the most beautiful/hard things in the study of combinatorics is the fact that is not just about memorizing 4 or 5 formulae but developing a whole reasoning ability.

Such thing can only be achieved by watching the maestros do their stuff and following their reasoning until one fully grasps the logic behind every decision made. I find more useful learning by applied example than by lengthy abstract theoretical disquisitions.

Can you please suggest online free places where one can find representative examples with understandable explanations?

thank you very much

Comment: Go to tags  of MSE search combinatorics,permutations

Comment: @ArchisWelankar yeah, that's one of the things i am doing. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

[Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/probability-and-combinatorics-topic) is a good website to try. 
You could also search for problems from past math competitions on [Art of Problem Solving](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) and on [Mathcounts Website](https://www.mathcounts.org/past-competitions).

If you need anything else, feel free to comment.

Comment: great places. gonna take a look at them, thank you.